# External Javascript File Fetch?

Tags: javascript, css

I am currently using this code:

```
var wordRandomizer = {
    run: function (targetElem) {
        var markup = this.createMarkup();
        targetElem.appendChild(markup);
    },
    createMarkup: function () {
        var that = this;
        var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
        this.elem = document.createElement('span');
        var button = document.createElement('button');
        button.innerText = 'Change Item';
        button.addEventListener('click', function () {
            that.changeItem();
        });
        frag.appendChild(this.elem);
        frag.appendChild(button);
        return frag;
    },
    changeItem: function () {
        var rand = this.getRandInt(1, this.items.length) - 1;
        console.log(rand);
        this.elem.innerText = this.items[rand];
    },
    getRandInt: function (min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    },
    items: ['itemA', 'itemB', 'itemC', 'itemD']
};
wordRandomizer.run(document.body);
```

I code is a button which when pressed grabs one of the items in the list. However, I don't want the items to show on the same page as the generator as people simply look at the source code. How can I make it so once the button is pressed it grabs the random item from another location where people cannot view them all using the source code.

If it helps, you can see the code in action here - http://jsbin.com/ESOdELU/1/edit

Comment: If you really need to keep this list out of the hands of the users, you'll need some server language - doesn't matter which (ASP.NET, PHP, Rails, etc.). If you're trying to accomplish this with static HTML/JS or plaintext data sources, your user will be able to see the list.

Comment: For that you'll have to use some server-side programming and ajax to use it.

Comment: If this runs in a browser then the user can see everything that the script can see.

Comment: @JoeEnos Thanks for the answer. Can you guide me on how to get started with that?

Comment: @remyabel Yes they can but it ruins the element of having the button there because every visitor will just view source if they know how. I'm not trying to stop visitors from viewing the data but make it so they have to use the button :)

Comment: @CCC If you're in a Windows environment, ASP.NET is the de facto web standard - there are plenty of free tools from Microsoft, and lots of tutorials online. If you're in the Linux or Mac world, PHP is very popular (even though it's an awful language IMO), and there are plenty of tutorials out there. If you're doing this for a company, they've probably got an existing infrastructure in place, so just ask the software team for help getting started. If you're on your own, then you've got a lot of basic web development tutorials to read up on to make your decision.

Comment: Alternatively, you could look into node.js and stick with the JavaScript you already know.

Comment: @ColinDeClue has a good idea there - I always forget about Node.js, but the few times I've tried it with simple "hello world" setups, it was ridiculously easy. If you don't get too fancy, you should be up and running in no time.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you a solution using PHP since it is a free scripting language and is the most likely to be supported by a host or default web server...

For starters, here is the code to include jquery and the basic AJAX script

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/JavaScript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("#generate").click(function(){ 
    $("#madlibs p").load("script.php");
  }); 
}); 
</script>
```

Here is the code for **script.php**

```
<?php 
header("Cache-Control: no-cache"); 
// For testing you can use an inline array like the lines below
// Just remove the comment slashes "//" from the beginning of the line
// and comment out the external declarations

//$actors = array('Denzel Washington','Michael J. Fox','Jim Carey','Boris Kodjoe'); 
//$roles = array('Mental Patient','Homeless Musician','Drag Queen Detective','Tormented Mathematician');

// In production, you would put these in a text file or a database.
// For $actors, put an entry on each line of a text file and save it as 'leads.txt'  
// Do the same with a separate file for $roles (roles.txt). 
$actors = file("leads.txt");
$roles = file("roles.txt");

// This selects a random element of each array on the fly 
echo $prefixes[rand(0,count($actors)-1)] . " stars as a "  
   . $suffixes[rand(0,count($roles)-1)] . " in the next blockbuster film."; 
// Example output: 
// Michael J. Fox stars as a Tormented Mathematician in the next blockbuster film.
?>
```

Put this in the body of your page and be sure to style everything up for display.

```
<body>
    <div id="madlibs"><p> </p></div> 
    <button id="generate">Surprise Me!</button> 
</body>
```

A couple of notes:
- You can include your basic layout HTML in the script.php file and then would only need the ID of the DIV in which you will be displaying the result *$("#madlibs")*

- You can use any server side language to achieve the same result, just swap out the external file call to the appropriate name and extension (.asp, .cfm, etc.)

Here is a link to the original tutorial that helped me with a similar project:
http://www.sitepoint.com/ajax-jquery/

I hope this helps.  Sorry, but I couldn't come up with a purely Java of JavaScript solution on lunch.